# making viber's sticker grid like gridview

Tags: android, gridview

I'm working in a stickers/decals app and I want to know if there is any library available which is similar to viber's sticker gridview? You see, there is an irregular shaped imageview item with auto adjusting rows and columns.

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: Can you have the screenshot of what you actually need??

Comment: Check the emojini library of watsapp application https://github.com/Grishu/emojicon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:
[Grid](https://github.com/talapbekov/FluidGridAdapter)

with this library you can get autoadjusting gridview